# Hiding element on body click

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).on('click','body', function(e){
      if(e.target == $('.moreOptionsMenu')){
        return false;
      }else{
        $('.moreOptionsMenu').remove();
      }
});

$(document).on('click','.fa.fa-bars.moreOptions', function(e){
e.stopPropagation();
  $('body').append('<div class="moreOptionsMenu">something</div>');
});
```

```css
.moreOptionsMenu{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
.moreOptions{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fa fa-bars moreOptions"></div>
```

I am having some problem with removing some element on click on body but where target is not on that or some other element:

```
$(document).on('click','body', function(e){
      if(e.target !== $('.moreOptionsMenu') && e.target !== $('.fa.fa-bars.moreOptions')){
        $('.moreOptionsMenu').remove();
      }
});

$(document).on('click','.fa.fa-bars.moreOptions', function(e){
  $('body').append('<div class="moreOptionsMenu">something</div>');
});
```

When I click on `.fa.fa-bars.moreOptions` I append `.moreOptionsMenu`, I want to remove `.moreOptionsMenu` when I click anywhere but on it or `.fa.fa-bars.moreOptions`.

With the code from above it is removing it every time.

Comment: Please add the related HTML and CSS so we can recreate your scenario.

Comment: Please formulate your question properly with the requirement and appropriate example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to use e.stopPropagation() to stop the event from bubbling up. For instance:

```
$(document).on('click','.fa.fa-bars.moreOptions', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('body').append('<div class="moreOptionsMenu">something</div>');
});
```

Comment: That works, if I knew about it I would try it :/ Thanks

Comment: Can you up vote the answer, so the question shows as answered?

Comment: It works for one part, but it doesn't work for another, when I click n appended div it closes and I don't need that but for half right I will accept it